# Task Schedular VBScript to generate a Message Pop-up

Tags: vbscript, wmi, scheduler

I need to create a task made in Vb Script for  Windows Vista & Windows 7 that will show a message pop-up to the user. **That task will run every Monday and Friday at 9am. The message window should contain 2 button (Yes/No). For Yes->Open a web-link and No->Exit**.

I found some information on internet but that is all about starting a program like Notepad. 
Example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394601%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

I am not able to find how to generate a message popup along with buttons.
Can anyone help ? Thanks.

Comment: Start your research here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x%28v=vs.84%29.aspx and here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx (follow the link to .Exec). Avoid WMI if you can.

Comment: Thanks Horner, I have made the VBS file which is running perfectly. I just now want to schedule it.  I want to avoid doing the manual work because this VBS needs to be scheduled in the machines of my team mates. I dont want all of them to assign this VBS in the task schduler from GUI. Thats why now I need to choose WMI. I hope you understand.

Comment: Hi Horner, How can I use EXEC method to run a task even after the system restart ?

Answer (score -1):

```
choice = msgbox( " That task will run every Monday and Friday at 9am ", 3, "test ")
```

this should give you " yes, no and cancel " options.

Comment: Hi Timrau, How can I use this message in VBScript ?
And also how can I apply action on YES,No and Cancel buttons ?